# "all boot options are tried" after installation on Samsung Ativ Book 9 Lite

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, samsung

Hi i have the samsung ativ book 9 lite
I just installed ubuntu 13.10 after removing windows 8.1 and have gotten the error all boot options are tried, after the installation
After having a look around the forum ihave made sure that I have disabled secure boot and fast boot
However I think the problem may be that i have been unable to disable the framebuffer. I am getting no F6 option when I am trying to install ubuntu that will allow me to select nomodeset. 
I am a bit of a noob and do not understand what the grub prompt way is? Is there any way I can fix the error : "all boot options are tried press  key to recover ...  "
I would be extremely appreciative if you could give me a detailed answer.
Thanks and looking forward.

Answer (score 0):

Another user with Samsung ATIV.

Installing Ubuntu 13.10 on a Samsung ATIV Book 9 Plus

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2203824

With UEFI systems you should have two boot options for flash drive, one BIOS and one UEFI. The BIOS boot is the purple screen with tiny accessiblity icons at bottom of screen. Press any key then f6.
If booting in UEFI mode you get grub menu which is just like a boot after install. You can press e on entry you want to edit, scroll down to linux line and replace quiet splash with nomodeset.

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)